# windows validation gone after changing pc

Tags: windows-7, validation

I have acer Aspire 5742z PEW71 laptop. It have Intel Pentium P6100 processor (type is unknown)
CPU Speed: 2.4 GHz,
Hard Drive: 500 GB,
RAM: 4 GB DDR3 with dual Channel ,
Screen Size: 15.5",

I needed all programs and the genuine windows 7 ultimate 64 bit installed in hard drive and I needed to run vmwearer. It,s processor don't support VT-X technology. So I open the hard drive and installed it on a desktop computer.

Here is its specifications foe desktop computer:

Processor: Intel Core i7-2600 CPU
Mainboard: Gigabyte H61M-S2P-B3
Bios details

- Brand : Award Software International Inc.
- Version : F4
- Date: 10/17/2011

CPU Speed: 3.40 GHz,
Hard Drive-1: 1TB,
Hard Drive-2: 500GB(This is taken from laptop. This is also booth drive. I did not installed this hard drive until now on my laptop after installing it on desktop.),
RAM: 4 GB DDR3 with single channel ,
Screen Size: 32.0",

When I first powered the CPU, everything just going ok except the black wallpaper problem, windows genuine problem, you may be a victim of software counterfeiting, address a problem with broadcom netlink gigabit Ethernet device and some drivers are not comfortable with this PC. Then I saw there are some drivers missing. Like, Intel HD graphics, tp-link wn727n driver and many more.  So I run drive pack solution. It installed all the driver. so now I have 4 problem.

1st is black well paper. If I set any wallpaper from my hard drive, it just disappears after some time.When I go to [ Control Panel > Ease of Access > Ease of Access Center > Make the computer easier to use ] there is unchecked on Remove background images (where available).

2nd is windows is not genuine. I have a valid windows 7 ultimate. It was preinstalled on my laptop. But when I installed hard drive, I show me a message "Windows is not genuine". I have the product key back of my laptop.

3rd is "you may be a victim of software counterfeiting".I don't know much about this. But a month ago I replaced my booth screen,s windows logo to another gif image.

4th is:Showing a message on solve pc issues "address a problem with broadcom netlink gigabit Ethernet device". I have a broadcom network card built in my laptop. Now I have a TP-link wn727n wireless receiver. I can use Internet via Ethernet with no problem.

What is the solution for this problems?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The key you had on your laptop was probably an OEM key, which is tied to the motherboard. You can call the Windows Activation number, and go through a phone activation process. I had to do this several times when working in a PC repair shop and they never denied me activation. The activation number line is (888) 571-2048.

Comment: **t have Intel Pentium P6100 processor (type is unknown)**  - I have no idea what you mean by "type is unknown" there is only one "type" of that processor [intel® Pentium® Processor P6100](http://ark.intel.com/products/50175/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6100-3M-Cache-2_00-GHz)

Comment: You cannot run the installation from your Acer on the PC with the Gigabyte motherboard.  The only solution is to purchase a new license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your windows license is bound to the machine it came with.* If you migrate the hard disk to a new computer, you do *not* have a valid License.

That might not seem very logical (or even unfair), but that is the license that Microsoft gave you, and they are legally entitled to make them as they like.

Your only options are to move the hard disk back in the old computer, or buy a new license.

Note that if your old computer would have been unfixably *broken*, you could have called them and explained it and asked nicely, and they *might* have reinstated the license on the new hardware (but that's not a right you have)

Comment: It's definitely worth calling the activation phone line. I've called them several times with the same situation. They never have denied me reactivation, even when I tell them "I put the key in a different computer."

Answer (score -1):

yes you can call microsoft or if you don't like to call then install the program removewat and it's ok.It will remove your windows activation tool notification.